# Trouble with .format()

Tags: python, pandas, syntax

I am trying to use .format to format a URL so I can scrape multiple similar webpages.

when I pass

```
df = pd.read_html('https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/a/abrinal01/gamelog/2019')
df
```

I easily find the result I am looking for, however when I pass

```
letter = 'a'
player = str(players_from_2018[0])
year = '2019'

df = pd.read_html('https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/{}/{}/gamelog/{}').format(letter, player, year)
```

I get a value error no tables found.

If I print

```
print(('https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/{}/{}/gamelog/{}').format(letter, player, year))
```

I get the url I am looking for exactly:
`https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/a/abrinal01/gamelog/2019`

Is this a common problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot some brackets.

Try this:

`df = pd.read_html(('https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/{}/{}/gamelog/{}').format(letter, player, year))`

But I'd recommend the use of f-strings if your python version is 3.6+, for cleaner, more readable code:

`df = pd.read_html(f'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/{letter}/{player}/gamelog/{year}')`

Answer (score 1):

You have the parenthesis in the wrong place. Try this:

```
df = pd.read_html('https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/{}/{}/gamelog/{}'.format(letter, player, year))
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Dylan, either you add the missing bracket or remove the unnecessary bracket and add the missing one. This should also work:

```
df = pd.read_html('https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/{}/{}/gamelog/{}'.format(letter, player, year))
```

Answer (score -1):

Use f-string Formatting in Python

```
url = f'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/{letter}/{player}/gamelog/{year}'

df = pd.read_html(url)
df
```

Comment: No. Only 3.6+ version